# online collaborative code editing ide

Tags: javascript, node.js, codemirror

I am trying to build a collaborative code editor using node.js. I am able to make contents inside a textarea collaborative (multiple people can edit it simultaneously).

How to turn an existing textarea into a code editor using CodeMirror without replacing the textarea? (if I directly try to make the text area into editor using code mirror it will either replace it or create an editor below it without replacing it)

How do I make the existing text area into code editor?

Comment: And how do you want us to help you exactly ?

Comment: how do I make the existing text area into code editor?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place for the broad questions like that. Can you produce the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example and update the post? See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you share the code you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this should be somewhat simple. If one builds a synchronous editor, it should be event-based, isn't it in your case?

So you should be able to do 2 things: detect an edit (and send it to others) and programmatically change the content of the edit area once you recieve a message ("another guy has edited"). And that's not difficult to do:

- to detect editing, use the `change`/`changes` [events](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events)
- to set changes, use [content manipulation methods](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_content) like `setValue` or `replaceRange`

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now it is working here is the demo collaborative-ide.herokuapp.com/